# Finding the amount of terms needed for a specific error using the Alternating Series Estimation Theorem where there is a factorial in the denominator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Problem was in the form of (not the actual problem since I'm not looking for an exact answer)
the series: $3(-1)^n / n!$, how many terms do we need to add to get an error of $10^{-3}$.

While I solved the problem already, it seemed unconventional and I figured out it would be better to find the amount of terms needed.

Generally when solving these problems, we would use a equation to solve for $n$, but I was unsure what to do since there was a factorial.

How would one solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing as before.
The error is less than 
the last term,
so you want
$3/n! < .001$
or
$n! > 3000
$.

The factorials
starting at 4 are
24, 120, 720, 5040,
so n=7 has a term of
3/5040 < .001
so 6 terms will do.

What makes this harder
is there is no simple
inverse function
for factorial.

Comment: Thank you. There was a way given to solve it in my class but I didn't write it down since it was last minute. While this is correct it wasn't necessarily the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something about $n$ should be mentioned, since it is not, i will start with $n=0$. To have an idea about the possibilities to estimate 
$$
S = \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac 1{n!}(-3)^n=\exp(-3)
\approx 0.049787068367863\dots
$$
i will write only:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S 
&=
\frac 1{0!}
-
\frac 3{1!}
+
\frac {3^2}{2!}
-
\frac {3^3}{3!}
+
\frac {3^4}{4!}
-
\frac {3^5}{5!}
+
\underbrace{
\left(
\frac {3^6}{6!}
-
\frac {3^7}{7!}
\right)}_{\ge 0}
+
\underbrace{
\left(
\frac {3^8}{8!}
-
\frac {3^9}{9!}
\right)}_{\ge 0}
+
\dots
\\
&\ge
\frac 1{0!}
-
\frac 3{1!}
+
\frac {3^2}{2!}
-
\frac {3^3}{3!}
+
\frac {3^4}{4!}
-
\frac {3^5}{5!}
\ ,
\\[3mm]
S 
&=
\frac 1{0!}
-
\frac 3{1!}
+
\frac {3^2}{2!}
-
\frac {3^3}{3!}
+
\frac {3^4}{4!}
-
\frac {3^5}{5!}
+
\frac {3^6}{6!}
-
\underbrace{
\left(
\frac {3^7}{7!}
-
\frac {3^8}{8!}
\right)}_{\ge 0}
-
\underbrace{
\left(
\frac {3^9}{9!}
-
\frac {3^{10}}{10!}
\right)}_{\ge 0}
+
\dots
\\
&\le
\frac 1{0!}
-
\frac 3{1!}
+
\frac {3^2}{2!}
-
\frac {3^3}{3!}
+
\frac {3^4}{4!}
-
\frac {3^5}{5!}
+
\frac {3^6}{6!}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have the above lower and upper estimates, and the difference is the last term we stopped at.

The same argument works in general for alternating series built using monotone sequences $\searrow 0$ (at least after some point, as is the case in our case).

So for the given question, we stop at the point $N$ where $3^N/N!$ becomes less than the mentioned error.
In our case we have for instance:
$$
\frac {3^{13}}{13!}
\approx
0.000256033029470529\dots
\ .
$$